# Laptop gets unexpected hard resets when using apt-get

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, apt

I am not able to install any software or update my packages anymore. A sudden reset happens everytime apt-get (upgrade, install or autoremove) finishes downloading and (apparently) right after grub comes in action.

My laptop is an Asus G750 with Windows 8 pre-installed on the HDD (which I barely use) and Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS installed on an SSD (which I use frequently and I am using now).

I have screen-captured the exact moment when the system resets. These results are after executing sudo apt-get autoremove.
[image: screenshot]

Note that I used to have this problem before and at some point I could not boot into Ubuntu anymore, therefore I reconfigured my HDD and installed another Ubuntu to perform backups. After that I wiped out my entire SSD and installed a fresh Ubuntu (however the older Ubuntu still stays in the HDD and apparently the laptop resets after grub finds it on sdb9). The problem still remains in the new freshly installed Ubuntu. Is it because Ubuntu is residing on SSD? Or is it because grub cannot handle multiple OSs on different hard drives?

What is causing this? And is there any way to force grub to skip scanning the other HDD after every apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

What you see in that photograph is **not** a system reset (or reboot), it is just the output of the command `update-grub`.

When installing or removing packages, sometimes additional actions are required to properly setup or clean up the environment.

The process of installation and removal for kernel packages always runs `update-grub` to generate a new GRUB configuration file. You can run it manually, it's harmless:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

> I am not able to install any software or update my packages anymore

There's not enough information to say anything about that. Maybe it's related to what we can see in the first line of the photograph: "1 not fully installed or removed". You have to provide more information (the command you ran and its full output).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have executed the command as you suggested, the PC resets itself once grub reaches to "Found Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (14.04) on /dev/sdb9"

I cannot save the output in some file like "sudo update-grub > res.txt" because the PC resets and I lose all unsaved data.

Comment: @user2452253 This definitely shouldn't happen. Seems like a bug or hardware problem. There are anything unusual while running Windows?